# How can we compute the minimum bounding sphere enclosing a 3D mesh object?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, 3d

I want to plot a sphere unit around a 3D object (.obj format file) with matlab, in order to guarantee a normalization of all the objects in my DB, and so on to achieve the scale invariance. I found in the state of the art that there are some algorithms implemented with C++ like Gartner's algorithm that is the fastest https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html, Fisher's algorithm which is more efficient for high dimensions https://github.com/hbf/miniball or  welzl'one, or Mogiddo's algorithm too.

My question is: does the function sphere in matlab do the same thing, so all we have to do is to change the center of the sphere, or there is a specific matlab implementation for one of those algorithms above?

Comment: MATLAB's `sphere` function simply draws a sphere, so I don't think that's what you're looking for. I don't know of any built-in functions to find the minimum bounding sphere, but there seem to be several implementations on File Exchange. Have you looked at those?

Comment: Ok thank you yes I have just found it, I was searching but it seems that I didn't use the appropriate keywords, So I would to thank you for your interaction and explanation. this is the function https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48725-exact-minimum-bounding-spheres-circles.